# Access is denied on mklink

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008-r2, symbolic-link, mklink

I am trying to get a symlink working over a network drive.

I have already tried suggestions on questions already asked, such as running as administrator and checking if the directory already exists.  Unfortunately it still gives me the following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>mklink /d \\myserver\SomeDir\SomeLink \\myserver\SomeOtherDir\MyDir
Access is denied.
```

Where SomeLink is the link I am attempting to create and Mydir is the directory I am trying to create it on.

Any ideas how I could get this working?  The local machine is running windows 7 and the remote machine is running windows server 2008 R2 standard.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Robert is wrong. Remotely mklink DOES work. Here is the solution:

Run command prompt as admin and then run this command:

```
fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation
```

If you see message "Remote to remote symbolic links are disabled.", then run this command:

> fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation R2R:1

After that, you can run

> mklink /d \\myserver\SomeDir\SomeLink \\myserver\SomeOtherDir\MyDir

Comment: Well, ill be damned, it works. Good first answer, welcome to SuperUser! I hope your future answers are as informative as this one. (FYI to people using this, the network link worked fine for me, but I had another person connect to the remote machine from his machine, they could see the link but got a permissions error when they tried to follow it)

Comment: Is there a security risk if I enable links from remote locations? Or some program's security model relies on this being disabled? I can't think of anything but maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

By default mklink only affects the local computer. Remote manipulations are not possible in that case.

Therefore if you want to add a symbolic directory link on a remote machine try to execute mklink.exe via [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) on the remote server, then using the local directory path of the two directories.

Comment: I thought that was the difference between symbolic links and  NTFS junctions - that they could work over network locations. http://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link

Comment: That linked answer is working locally (\\alice\C$ from computer alice becomes C:\), but uses the share name. What you can do is mounting a remote share to a local directory: [Mount Remote CIFS/SMB Share as a Folder not a Drive Letter](http://serverfault.com/questions/105633/mount-remote-cifs-smb-share-as-a-folder-not-a-drive-letter)