# Symbolic linking in an SMB share?

Tags: smb

I have read/write access to an SMB share, but I do not have access to the box itself. My end goal is to create a symbolic link of some sort inside the share to another share, so that other devices connected can access the share. My problem is that the devices I have connected to the share have a hard coded reference to the shares and I cannot add anymore ... e.g., they only see this:

```
\\networkshare1\videos
```

And I have:

```
\\networkshare2\videos
```

I do not have anything besides file system access to networkshare1, but I do have full permissions for the folders.

I'd like to have something like:

```
\\networkshare1\videos\folderlink
```

And if you hit that directory the networkshare2 videos folder is exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic links to network shares are not allowed.

Comment: Is there anyway I can achieve my end result, without symbolic links?

Comment: @chumofchance I don't know for sure. It may be possible using [DFS, Distributed File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_(Microsoft)).

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov [Actually they are allowed](http://superuser.com/a/637887/25625), just not by default.

Answer (score 0):

if you can create a symlink to the actual disk location instead of the share, you can set 'follow symlinks = yes ' in your smb.conf, and it will work. I have my nas set up the same way, so that content from multiple disks can be exposed via a single share.

if you can't acutally create the symlink on the server, then you will have to try Scott Chamberlain's advice above.

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you are not allowed to create symbolic links for network shares, But instead you can create "Desktop shortcut"

Comment: Are you sure about that statement? I mean, you can create a drive mapping to a network share and create a symbolic link to that location, isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Where did you read this?As far as I know this is not true, you just need elevated rights to do so.