# creating symbolic links on networked drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, symbolic-link

I'm trying to better organize my public folder at work and I need to maintain old links that I have emailed to people in the past. I'm thinking of creating symbolic links so that I can maintain those old folder links while moving my folders and files where I want them.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to do this because I'm working on networked drives.

Issuing the following command:

```
mklink /J "\\networkDrv\users\Me\Force Tester" "\\networkDrv\users\Me\File Store\Lappers\ASL_ABL\Code\Force Tester"
```

results in this error:

```
Local NTFS volumes are required to complete the operation.
```

Answer (score 9):

Try running command prompt as administrator and with the `/D` switch instead.

```
mklink /D "\\networkDrv\users\Me\Force Tester" "\\networkDrv\users\Me\File Store\Lappers\ASL_ABL\Code\Force Tester"
```

Run `mklink /?` from command prompt to get more details of the options of this command.

```
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```

---

**Access Denied Fix**

If you run the `mklink /D` command as administrator and the `Link` part of the command is a UNC network path and you get `Access Denied` error message, then follow the below to potentially resolve this issue.

1. On there server where *(and/or on the Windows client PC you're getting the Access Denied error message when you run the command)* the `Link` part of the command is located, run this command as administrator on the server: `fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation`
2. If you see `Remote to remote symbolic links are disabled.` then run this command: `fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation R2R:1`

   - You can run this from the location where you're running the MKLINK command and getting access denied whether on the Windows Server itself or the Windows client PC
3. Now try running your command again and hopefully it works successfully now.

**Link Reference:** [Access is denied on mklink](https://superuser.com/questions/449400/access-is-denied-on-mklink)

Comment: denied. I get 'Access is denied." I guess because I'm not an admin for the server.

Comment: Well I am running the console in admin mode

Comment: Ok, I will try that next. Right now, I was able to create the link on the desktop as per your last comment no problems. However, when I went to move the link to the network, it turned into an empty folder with a link to nowhere. So I guess the link got broken in the copying process

Comment: And yes, I do have write permissions, I can create and edit a text file

Comment: `Access is denied`, that's all I get

Comment: It seems like access is getting denied when the path on the left-hand side (the target) is on the network, but not when the target is local. And again, I'm not an admin on the server, nor do I have access to the physical server

Comment: Well the client PC is Windows 7. I'm not sure what the server PC is running and the guy that would know is out sick. Is there any way I can find out?

Comment: And again, I can't access the server, so that's out of the question, unfortunately

Comment: @audiFanatic I just edited my answer with a access denied fix section to outline the exact steps to take when you're able to for a potential solution.  Hopefully all works out for you when you're able to get to it.

Comment: All right, it was disabled, and not it is enebled. However, I'm still getting `access is denied` when I try to re-run the command.

Comment: I'd say run it from the server as well when you're able to and see if perhaps it needs enabled at that level: `On there server where (and/or on the Windows client PC you're getting the Access Denied error message when you run the command) the Link part of the command is located`