# Shortcut with property type=file folder

Tags: shortcuts

Anyone can advise how can i get a "file folder" type shortcut on win2008? 
In the shortcut properties, on general tab, the type is "file folder" instead of normal shortcut type.

I tried to drag target folder to start button and copy the shortcut but once checked the properties of the shortcut it shows as "shortcut".

Appreciate any answer how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're referring to something like this:

[image]

That's not a [Shell Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`.lnk` file). That's a [Junction Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point). You can create these junction points (and [Symbolic Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)) with the `mklink` command-line tool, or a [GUI tool](https://superuser.com/questions/260740/any-tool-to-create-symlinks-in-gui) if you prefer.

They will render in Explorer as a "File folder" type with a shortcut icon - but they're different from the "traditional" shortcuts. Primarily, they are part of the file system and will work outside Windows Explorer - e.g. cmd, PowerShell, Linux, will recognise and follow junctions and symlinks but not `.lnk` shortcuts.

And if you're curious about the difference between a junction and symlink, see ["directory junction" vs "directory symbolic link"?](https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link)

Comment: Thanks Bob! yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. by the way, can you advise is there any possible way to copy a junction point?

Comment: @galalaga On modern Windows OSes, you can use the `robocopy` command with the `/sl` option ("copy symbolic links versus the target").