# Windows file junction

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs, symbolic-link

I have a backup solution which backs up a single folder of my hard disk. I want to "mount" files from various locations of my hard disk into this directory.

At first I tried creating symbolic links. However, when I restore the backed up folder on a different computer, it restores symbolic links that point to nowhere. Instead I would like to have the physical files restored where the original symbolic links pointed to.

With directories I can get this behavior by creating a junction instead of a symbolic link. Is there a kind of "file junction" in Windows as well?

Comment: You may want to look at this utility. Link Shell Extension. I have no affiliation with the app or author.  https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html

Comment: I second @Hefewe1zen  I use the link shell extension almost every day.  You *can* do this stuff using the mklink command line utility but why bother?

Comment: DOUGH!  I forgot to help you! :) .. check out [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link).  It has lots of nifty chart showing the different options you have.  There are quite a few.  You should scroll through all of the posts.. there are many nice charts there.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS doesn't support "file junctions", the "directory junctions" it does support are implemented as "reparse points" on the filesystem level and don't support files.

Your backup solution is not traversing symbolic links and is instead copying the links themselves--and that's the real problem.  You may need to change the configuration of your backup solution or find another solution.  Robocopy, for example, to my understanding will traverse symbolic links like folders and copy the contents thereof, unless you tell it not to (with `/SL` or `/XJF`).