# Wildcard in directory junctions (or symbolic links)?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Directory Junctions allow a folder to be redirected to another location.

- so you could create a directory junction as: <kbd>C:\Users\Ian\Downloads\Torrents</kbd>
- and have it resolve to: <kbd>S:\Torrents</kbd>

This would appear in a directory listing as:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Ian\Downloads

10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     Torrents [S:\Torrents]
```

You can make a *directory junction* with the command:

```
C:\Users\Ian\Downloads>mklink /J Torrents S:\Torrents
```

Windows also uses this feature to help support buggy applications that don't follow [the rules.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) You can see this if you get a directory listing of your profile folder:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Ian

10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     Application Data [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming]
10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     Cookies [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies]
10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     Local Settings [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local]
10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     My Documents [C:\Users\Ian\Documents]
10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     NetHood [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     PrintHood [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     Recent [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     SendTo [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     Start Menu [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
10/03/2020  01∶19 ᴘᴍ    <JUNCTION>     Templates [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates]
```

All those folders were the default locations in Windows 2000, but were moved in later versions of Windows. Windows continues to create those folders as **junctions** because of the disgusting number of applications that assume those are valid locations of anything.

```
C:\Users\Ian
|-- Application Data → [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming]
|-- Cookies → [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies]
|-- Local Settings → [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local]
|-- My Documents → [C:\Users\Ian\Documents]
|-- NetHood → [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
|-- PrintHood → [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
|-- Recent → [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
|-- SendTo → [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
|-- Start Menu → [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
|-- Templates → [C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates]
```

### Second generation of lousy programs

For 26 years now, since Windows 95, applications are supposed to store their *application data* in `CSIDL_APPDATA`:

`SHGetFolder(CSIDL_APPDATA)` → <kbd>D:\Users\AppData\Roaming</kbd>

There is a plague of new applications that are also not following the rules. They are dumping their garbage in the user's home folder, rather than the *application data* folder. For example:

```
Ian
|-- .borland
|-- .cache
|-- .config
|-- .dotnet
|-- .gitconfig
|-- .idlerc
|-- .lemminx
|-- .MakeMKV
|-- .MCTranscodingSDK
|-- .nuget
|-- .omnisharp
|-- .pylint.d
|-- .QtWebEngineProcess
|-- .redhat
|-- .SimulationCraft
|-- .ssh
|-- .vscode
```

This is all completely, and totally wrong. Not only does it violate the Windows programming contract, not only does it dump stuff in the wrong folder, not only does it clutter up my home folder with things that are not ***mine***, but it consumes drive space when i **explicitly** told these apps to store their data elsewhere (in the **appdata** folder on the bigger drive).

Now, i have no hope of these application developers fixing their buggy applications; they're obviously Linux or Javascript programmers, who don't know how to write real applications. And if they haven't been able to figure it out after 26 years: they're not gonna now.

Obviously what i **can** do is move the contents of all these folders to their correct home in `CSIDL_AppData`, and then create the *junction* (or *symbolic link*) for each of them:

```
Ian
|-- .borland &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.borland]
|-- .cache &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.cache]
|-- .config &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.config]
|-- .dotnet &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.dotnet]
|-- .gitconfig &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.gitconfig]
|-- .idlerc &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.idlerc]
|-- .lemminx &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.lemminx]
|-- .MakeMKV &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.MakeMKV]
|-- .MCTranscodingSDK &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.MCTranscodingSDK]
|-- .nuget &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.nuget]
|-- .omnisharp &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.omnisharp]
|-- .pylint.d &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.pylint]
|-- .QtWebEngineProcess &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.QtWebEngineProcess]
|-- .redhat &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.redhat]
|-- .SimulationCraft &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.SimulationCraft]
|-- .ssh &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.ssh]
|-- .vscode &rarr; [D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.vscode]
```

But i'd have to do that manually for every existing folder. But then i would miss every new piece of crap-ware that dumps its garbage on the sidewalk.

What would be *great* is if directory junctions (or even symbolic links) supported a wildcard:

```
mklink /J C:\Users\Ian\.* D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\.*
```

I know `mklink` doesn't do that; but:

- it doesn't hurt to ask
- maybe someone has another idea

### Bonus Reading

- [Dotfile madness](https://0x46.net/thoughts/2019/02/01/dotfile-madness/)
- Raymond Chen: [Stop the madness: Subdirectories of My Documents](https://web.archive.org/web/20171105053854/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061228-02/?p=28563)
- ["directory junction" vs "directory symbolic link"?](https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link)

### Bonus Chatter

Along the same lines, there is the disgusting number of applications that dump their junk into **My** Documents folder:

```
D:\Users\Ian\Documents
|-- .AccessibilityInsights
|-- .Adobe
|-- .Adobe Scripts
|-- .AdobeStockPhotos
|-- .Aerofly FS 2
|-- .AeroFS
|-- .Axialis Librarian
|-- .BabeLua
|-- .Battlefield 3
|-- .Black & White 2
|-- .Blackbird_data
|-- .Borland Studio Projects
|-- .Colossal Order
|-- .com.nolimitscoaster.nolimits2
|-- .CommView
|-- .Curse
|-- .Dash
|-- .Diablo III
|-- .Dungeon Siege
|-- .Dungeon Siege LOA
|-- .EA Games
|-- .Embarcadero
|-- .Fiddler2
|-- .FlashIntegro
|-- .Flight Simulator X Files
|-- .Heroes of the Storm
|-- .Hitman Blood Money
|-- .Host Integration Projects
|-- .IISExpress
|-- .inblock
|-- .MessageAnalyzer
|-- .My Curse
|-- .My Data Sources
|-- .My Games
|-- .My Virtual Machines
|-- .My Web Sites
|-- .MyFlash
|-- .Oculus Home
|-- .Pascal Analyzer
|-- .Prepar3D Files
|-- .Project CARS
|-- .Rec Room
|-- .Reflector
|-- .Remote Assistance Logs
|-- .RESTDebugger
|-- .SimCity
|-- ....
|-- .zion
```

If you see your app in this list: please fix it. My **Documents** folder is for **My** documents - not your application data.

Comment: Q&A site. Not a blog&rant site.

Comment: @user1686 Now that i've given enough motivation for the question, and research effort, do you have anything useful to say?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do wildcards. Make a link to a folder containing the files.. a directory junction or symbolic link. It can't do * because each junction needs to point to a specific parse point of a real item.. good luck.