# Getting "Access is denied" when moving a folder to a symlink which is pointing to another drive

Tags: command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, symbolic-link, move

I have a drive named D and a drive named E. I created a folder named "test" in drive D and a folder named "destination" in drive E using the mkdir command. Then in D I created a symlink using the following command:

```
mklink /D D:\source E:\destination
```

Now, when I try to move the folder named "test" from D to D:\source using the command `move D:\test D:\source`, I get an error message simply saying "Access is denied". If I try to move a *file* named "test.txt" with the command `move D:\test.txt D:\source`, I get no error and the file is moved to E:\destination successfully.

I also tried to do this in powershell with the command `mv D:\test\ D:\source\` and got the same result but I got a longer error message which reads:

```
mv : Access to the path 'D:\test\' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ mv D:\test\ D:\source\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\test\:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Interestingly, I just noticed that moving the test folder directly to the destination folder using `move D:\test E:\destination` also triggers the "Access is denied" error. So my problem might not relate specifically to symlink. However moving the folder in powershell with `move D:\test E:\destination` works fine (whereas it was failing when it was a symlink). It's very strange.

Why am I getting this access denied error and why does it only return an error if I try to move a folder and not a file? Also why does directly moving the folder fail in cmd but succeeds in powershell? Is there anything I can do to circumvent the error?

Note: I tried all the commands as Administrator.

Here is the security tab of the destination folder's properties:

[image: security tab of destination folder's properties]

And here is the security tab of the test folder's properties:

[image: security tab of test folder's properties]

Comment: By "I tried all the commands as Administrator", do you mean that you ran CMD and PowerShell using "Run as Administrator"? If no - please try it. If yes - please add screenshots of the Properties of the two folders Security tab.

Comment: @harrymc yes, I ran cmd and powershell using "run as administrator". I added screenshots of the folder properties' security tab.

Comment: Do Administrators have Full control on both folders?

Comment: @harrymc yes...

Comment: This then doesn't look like a permissions problem. Is it possible that one of the folders is sometimes used/locked by some program? Try doing it while booting in Safe mode.

Comment: @harrymc doubtful as I just created both folders with mkdir before creating the symlink but I can try the safe mode thing later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting issue which got me thinking. @harrymc is right.  This does not have to do with permissions.

### There is a difference where you use `move` at `cmd.exe` or `PowerShell`

`move` command at `cmd.exe` is **different** program than `move` from `PowerShell`.  `Move` at `PowerShell` is
actually only an alias for `Move-Item` whereas `move` is an internal `cmd.exe` command.  See below **Notes** for the difference!

### The issue

This issue will be the same for symbolic links or Junctions (for more on the differences see [directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link](https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link)).

The issue is that the internal function of `move` (`cmd.exe`) and `Move-Item` (`PowerShell`) can't handle the *drive volume change*.  In essence it is same as [Move-Item the regression](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/15077) for PowerShell 7.2.  The core of the issue is that the function `MoveTo()` can not handle the *drive volume change* (on the symlink) and there has to be a fallback to `CopyAndDelete()` function.

### The solution

### @cmd.exe

The solution for `cmd.exe` is to use `robocopy` (`c:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe`).  The `robocopy` depreciates `xcopy` at Windows 10.  `xcopy` could also be used, but will be probably removed in the future so the examples are for `robocopy` only.

**An example:**

To move a directory to a symbolic link dir:

a) `robocopy d:\test d:\destination /E /MOVE`

`/E : Copy Subfolders, including Empty Subfolders.`

`/MOVE : Move files and dirs (delete from source after copying).`

**Please note a feature:** that if the directory `d:\test` is empty it won't be moved but it will get deleted.

b) `robocopy d:\test d:\destination /S /MOV`

`/S : Copy Subfolders.`
`/MOV : MOVe files (delete from source after copying).`

Copies non-empty subfolders and removes **files only** after copying.

### @PowerShell

You could use the `robocopy.exe` here too, but if you want to do it natively for all PowerShell versions, you have to use `copy&delete` (similar to the "fix" above when there is a fall back for *drive volume change* on symlink).

Here it is on one line:

`Copy-Item -Path d:\test -Destination d:\destination; Delete-Item -Path d:\test`

**Note:** Should you have issue with `Delete-Item` you can try to use the `-Force` switch.

I'm using `PowerShell 5.1.18362.1801` the moving of directory regression will be probably fixed in later versions.

### Notes

**`PowerShell` move**

```
NAME
    Move-Item

SYNTAX
    Move-Item [-Path] <string[]> [[-Destination] <string>] [-Force] [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>
    ] [-PassThru] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Move-Item [[-Destination] <string>] -LiteralPath <string[]> [-Force] [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <stri
    ng[]>] [-PassThru] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    mi
    mv
    move


REMARKS
    Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
        -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
        -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help Move-Item -Online" or
           go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113350.
```

**`cmd.exe` move:**

```
move /?
Moves files and renames files and directories.

To move one or more files:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination

To rename a directory:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]dirname1 dirname2

  [drive:][path]filename1 Specifies the location and name of the file
                          or files you want to move.
  destination             Specifies the new location of the file. Destination
                          can consist of a drive letter and colon, a
                          directory name, or a combination. If you are moving
                          only one file, you can also include a filename if
                          you want to rename the file when you move it.
  [drive:][path]dirname1  Specifies the directory you want to rename.
  dirname2                Specifies the new name of the directory.

  /Y                      Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to
                          overwrite an existing destination file.
  /-Y                     Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite
                          an existing destination file.

The switch /Y may be present in the COPYCMD environment variable.
This may be overridden with /-Y on the command line.  Default is
to prompt on overwrites unless MOVE command is being executed from
within a batch script.
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm primarily interested in Powershell since I am using that lately. Based on your comment "...the moving of directory regression will be probably fixed in later versions" are you saying that failing to move folders into symlinked directories is a bug?

Comment: @Cave Johnson You are welcome. Yes, it is a regression. The isssue here is that the implemantation does not take the *drive volume change* into account. Therefore, it does not have a fallback for that workfow.